# How many dwarves of Thorin's ex company were alive during The War of Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

I googled something about this, and somewhere I've found an information which says that 7 dwarves of Thorin's ex company were alive during the War of Ring, but I can't find it again.
Anyway, on LOTR Wikia, it says the same thing - Dwalin, Bifur, Bofur, Bombur, Gloin, Nori and Dori were alive, while Thorin, Fili and Kili died in The Battle of the Five Armies, Balin died of sickness, Ori got killed by goblins and Oin got eaten by The Watcher in the Water. Is that written in Silmarillion, or it's just a ''fanmade'' information?

Comment: I don't have the books to hand, but the Hobbit will tell you which dwarves died at the Battle of Five Armies. When the Fellowship of the Ring finds Balin's tomb in Moria, Gandalf reads a record of the colony, and this will tell you which other dwarves died there.

Comment: The Silmarillion would not have that sort of information. While it has been a couple decades since I read it, I can say it's a prequel (by thousands of years) to the whole Hobbit/LotR set.

Comment: As per *The Fellowship of the Ring* and Cearon O'Flynn's answer below, Balin was murdered by an orc, and *did not* die of sickness.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

We have the following:

Per *The Hobbit*:

- Kíli Dies at the Battle of Five Armies.
- Fíli Dies at the Battle of Five Armies.
- Thorin Dies at the Battle of Five Armies.

> Of the twelve companions of Thorin, ten remained. Fíli and Kíli had fallen defending him with shield and body, for he was their mother's elder brother.
>
> <sub>***The Hobbit - Chapter 18: "The Return Journey"***</sub>

Per *The Fellowship of the Ring*:

- Balin is definitely dead by the time of the War of the Ring. His tomb is in Khazad Dûm - he was killed by orcs at least 34 years before the fellowship found his tomb - recorded in the Book of Mazarbul.
- Óin is dead by the time of the War of the Ring, killed by the Watcher in the Water as he tried to escape - as recorded in the book of Mazarbul.

  > "...the pool is up to the wall at Westgate. The Watcher in the Water took Óin."
  >
  > <sub>***The Lord of the Rings - The Fellowship of the Ring - "The Bridge of Khazad-Dûm"***</sub>
- Ori is dead, killed in Khazad Dûm. He made the last entry in the Book of Mazarbul.

  > "The end comes ... drums, drums in the deep ... they are coming."
  >
  > <sub>***The Lord of the Rings - The Fellowship of the Ring - "The Bridge of Khazad-Dûm"***</sub>
- Glóin is alive and present at the Council of Elrond.
- Dwalin, Dori, Nori, Bifur, Bofur, and Bombur are all still living at Erebor, as told by Glóin at the feast in Rivendell:

  > He was interested, however, to hear that Dáin was still King under the Mountain, and was now old (having passed his two hundred and fiftieth year), venerable, and fabulously rich. Of the ten companions who had survived the Battle of Five Armies seven were still with him: Dwalin, Glóin, Dori, Nori, Bifur, Bofur, and Bombur.
  >
  > <sub>***The Lord of the Rings - The Fellowship of the Ring - "Of Many Meetings"***</sub>

According to the appendices in *The Return of the King*, Glóin died in 15 FA, and Dwalin died in 3112 TA (equivalent to 91 FA). The deaths of the rest of the living dwarves are not recorded.

Comment: It is also worth noting that, by the time of the War of the Ring, that Bombur had become so fat and heavy that six young dwarves were required to carry him around as he could no longer move around himself (from the chapter concerning Frodo's arrival in Rivendell in the Fellowship of the Ring).

Comment: @maguirenumber6 that is right took six dwarves to carry him around

Comment: I added the quote from Gloin listing the seven living members, and removed the references to the appendixes, which are now unnecessary.

Comment: @Plutor thank you I was looking all through the Council of Elrond not realising it was in the next chapter. Many thanks

Comment: I added the quote for Fíli and Kíli's deaths from *The Hobbit*

Comment: I am surprised why this answer has not been accepted yet, +1 for such detailed description.

Comment: Thanks for the detail need to go to @plutor @ jason-baker for adding the extras i missed

Comment: Only thing missing now is Óin, whose entry basically just says the same as in the question; where is it stated that Óin was killed by the Watcher in the Water?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the book of Mazarbul - quotes added